# How to correct "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in recursive function?

Tags: python

```
def Ancestors (otu,tree):
    if tree[otu][0][0] == None:
       return []
    else:
        return [otu,tree[otu][0][0]] + Ancestors (tree[otu][0][0],tree)
```

The problem essentially is that at some point, the function tries to call a something which is None, this happens instead of the function returning the list that I want. I thought the if statement had accounted for that, but it would seem I was wrong. Any advice?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    Ancestors('A',a)
  File "C:\x.py", line 129, in Ancestors
    return [otu,tree[otu][0][0]] + Ancestors (tree[otu][0][0],tree)
  File "C:\x.py", line 129, in Ancestors
    return [otu,tree[otu][0][0]] + Ancestors (tree[otu][0][0],tree)
  File "C:\x.py", line 129, in Ancestors
    return [otu,tree[otu][0][0]] + Ancestors (tree[otu][0][0],tree)
  File "C:\x.py", line 129, in Ancestors
    return [otu,tree[otu][0][0]] + Ancestors (tree[otu][0][0],tree)
  File "C:\x.py", line 126, in Ancestors
    if tree[otu][0][0] == None:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This is what tree is

```
{'A': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'C': [('ADBFGC', 14.5), None, None], 'B': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'E': [('ADBFGCE', 17.0), None, None], 'D': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'G': [('BFG', 6.25), None, None], 'F': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'ADBFG': [('ADBFGC', 6.25), ('AD', 4.25), ('BFG', 2.0)], 'BF': [('BFG', 5.75), ('B', 0.5), ('F', 0.5)], 'ADBFGC': [('ADBFGCE', 2.5), ('ADBFG', 6.25), ('C', 14.5)], 'ADBFGCE': [None, ('ADBFGC', 2.5), ('E', 17.0)], 'BFG': [('ADBFG', 2.0), ('BF', 5.75), ('G', 6.25)], 'AD': [('ADBFG', 4.25), ('A', 4.0), ('D', 4.0)]}
```

with otu referring to any of the strings in the tree.

Comment: Generally speaking, when you get a `TypeError` it means that your values aren't what you think they are. This is a good place to use a debugger.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This simply means that either `tree`, `tree[otu]`, or `tree[otu][0]` evaluates to `None`, and as such is not subscriptable. Most likely `tree[otu]` or `tree[otu][0]`. Track it down with some simple debugging like this:

```
def Ancestors (otu,tree):
    try:
        tree[otu][0][0]
    except TypeError:
        print otu, tre[otu]
        raise
    #etc...
```

or [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

Comment: I tried debugging like you suggested, but every single value gets returned normally. As far as I can tell, eventually the recursive function hits a None value, but I thought my if statement accounted for that?

Comment: your `if` statement is actually where the error is being raised according to the stacktrace. Since I don't know the nature of your tree's data I can only guess, but I would guess that the check that you actually want to make is `if tree[otu] == None:`

Comment: Actually its if tree[otu][0] == None but we solved it! FYI I love you.

Comment: Damn I must be getting slow, I really should have seen that earlier

Comment: optional: or `if tree[otu][0] is None`. `==` may trigger an error msg in `flake8`

Answer (score 2):

One of the values you pass on to `Ancestors` becomes `None` at some point, it says, so check if `otu`, `tree`, `tree[otu]` or `tree[otu][0]` are `None` in the beginning of the function instead of only checking `tree[otu][0][0] == None`. But perhaps you should reconsider your path of action and the datatype in question to see if you could improve the structure somewhat.

Comment: One of the values does become None at some point later in the function, but there is no None at the beginning. How can I account for that?

Comment: Sure I'll add it in now to the original question, though it's quite long

Answer (score 1):

What is `a` when you call `Ancestors('A',a)`? If `a['A']` is None, or if `a['A'][0]` is None, you'd receive that exception.

Comment: Neither of them are None, I just put in a bunch of print statements in the function and all of them were returned fine. The problem I see now is that instead of stopping, the function continues to a point where there is None, how do I counter that??