# Error while printing variables from item container in pipeline, python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am unable print scraped value from pipeline using python scrapy.

in my python scrapy code i am yielding values to items container and these  items values need to be store in pipeline and return value. But it was throwing me type errors. Could you please help me here.

## pipeline.py

```
class JnjwcpocPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        print("Pipeline :" + item['product_item'][0])
        return item
```

Pipeline : JNJ BABY SOAP

> ERROR: Error processing {'product_item': None, 'wprice_item': None}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>
> print("Pipeline :" + item['product_item'][0])
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846442/how-to-correct-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable-in-recursive)

Comment: i checked there is no duplicate records

Answer (score 1):

`item['product_item']` seems to be `None`,so `item['product_item'][0]` is not callable, try to make it not `None` but a container and test it out.

If that's the problem, you can probably use some `if` to check it if it's `None`

Comment: Actually it is `item['product_item']` that is `None` as you can see from the error message what `item` looks like: `{'product_item': None, 'wprice_item': None}`

Comment: Thank for noticing That! I'll change my answer.

Comment: actually i can able to yield productname and price while scraping in python script.But my intention is to store the value in db and s fallowed some blogs and tested to print records from pipeline.

Comment: in my items container i am returning 2 attributes. but only calling one attribute in pipeline

Comment: try call ```item.product_item```

Comment: no luck by writing 
print("Pipeline :" + item.product_item)

Comment: @user11894930, the point is that `item['product_item']` returns `None`, so when you do `item['product_item'][0]`, that's like doing `None[0]` which is an error in python. The solution as indicated by this answer is to include a check like `if item['product_item'] is not None`, before trying to do `item['product_item'][0]`

Comment: it was very bad feeling to me to say i am very new to python coding. Could you please help me where should i put if clause

Comment: @user11894930 see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58569467/2089675

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to print items that might be ‘None’ try enclosing the print function in a ‘try:except’ block that will catch any exceptions and allow the items that aren’t None to be returned:

```
class JnjwcpocPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        print("Pipeline :" + item['product_item'][0])
        return item
    except:
        print('This has a NoneType object.')
```

Or:

```
class JnjwcpocPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        print("Pipeline :" + item['product_item'][0])

    except:
        pass

    finally:
        return item
```

Comment: i tried writing this .. below is the output
2019-10-26 13:00:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.xxxx.com/>
{'product_item': 'Free Skin Baby Wash  '
                 'Extract, 27.1 fl. oz',
 'wprice_item': '$5.92'}
Pipeline :F
2019-10-26 13:00:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.xxxx.com/>
{'product_item': "Free Skin  Baby Wash with Vanilla & "
                 'Oat Extract, 27.1 fl. oz',
 'wprice_item': '$5.92'}
This has a NoneType object.

Comment: You don’t have to include a print statement under the ‘except:’ block - you can just write ‘pass’ and that will skip over that item. If you want the item to be returned regardless of NoneType objects, just cut the ‘return item’ line and add it to a ‘finally:’ block at the end. Code edited to show this.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is telling you that `item['product_item']` is `None` type and therefore is not subscriptable. You should be checking this before trying to do: `item['product_item'][0]`.

```
class JnjwcpocPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        product_item = item['product_item']
        if product_item is not None: # <-- Check here
            print("Pipeline :" + product_item[0])
        return item
```